# find overlapping times in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've got an array of classes, and I want to find where there may be a schedule overlap.

My array is something like this

```
[
  {
    id:2,
    start: "3:30",
    length: 40,
    break: 30,
    num_attendees: 14
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "3: 40",
    length: 60,
    break: 40,
    num_attendees: 4
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: "4: 40",
    length: 30,
    break: 10,
    num_attendees: 40
  }
]
```

pretty simple. 
Now, I want to get an array where I add the start and the length, and then get the classes that overlap to notify the user that they have a conflict.

I know I can do a large for loop and compare that way, but I'm thinking there must be a nicer way to do this in Ruby, something like (ignore that we're not working in absolute minutes here, I've got that, I just want to keep the example simple).

```
overlap = class_list.select{|a,b| if a.start+a.length>b.start return a,b end}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#combination`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Array%3acombination) like this:

```
class_list.combination(2).select{|c1, c2|
  # here check if c1 and c2 overlap
}
```

Comment: That way, you'll get everything twice, and you'll compare elements with itself.

Comment: Not with `combination`. With `product` or `permutation`, yes.

Comment: thanks mladen, that's kinda working, is the best way to put the results into an array to do `find_overlap << [c1,c2]`??

Comment: No, `select` already outputs only the results that pass the test (the ones the block returns `true` for).